# Changing a dropdown list to in-line with CSS

Tags: html, css

[Top: Current situation, Bottom: What I'm trying to acheive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFovX.jpg)

I am attempting to modify the language switcher at the top of this Wordpress-based website so that both the flags display next to each other, inline, without having to first hover.

https://www.furuhostel.com/

I can't figure it out, so was wondering if anyone could help? Maybe it's not possible with CSS!

Thank you!

Comment: share your codes, please. the problem here seems to tell. You applied positon absolute, but you applied it as px, so it doesn't change in size. If you want to adjust itself according to any size, you can give it as"%." But like I said, it would be clearer if you shared your codes.

Comment: @CanUver Thanks for your response. I don't have any codes, it's a plugin made by TranslatePress, all I can do is adjust the CSS and test it using Inspect in Chrome.

I'll add an image of what I mean (if that's possible)

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in your code, change these classes.

```
 #trp-floater-ls.trp-floater-ls-flags {
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    left: 75%;
 }

 #trp-floater-ls-current-language {
    display: none !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }


 #trp-floater-ls-language-list {
    display: flex !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I added this into the custom CSS section in Wordpress but nothing changed and I can't find any reference to trp-floater-ls in Inspect - I'm assuming there's something I don't understand as I'm very new to all this.
Is there a better way for me to implement this?

Comment: I changed all this code in your website inspector in google chrome. Tell you step by step what need to be done.. don't worry

Answer (score -1):

I have inspecting the element within chrome as no code has been supplied for this example but from what I can see you need to:
Remove the currently selected item `trp-floater-ls-current-language` (I did this by just `display:none`). 
Where the class `trp-language-switcher-container` is, you will need to remove the defined width of 50px so that the container takes the size of its children. 
And lastly you will need to set the class `trp-floater-ls-language-list` to `display: flex`. 
Hope this helps and is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I can't find trp-floater-ls-current-language when inspecting the element in chrome, do I have to filter a different state or something?

Comment: With wordpress you need to be very specific with the css. Add !important (as much as you shouldnt you have to) to the end of the above and target the childs parent class and then the class you are working with